# How to forward list containing js objects to asp.net core mvc?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I generate the js object, which looks as follows:

```
cartStorage = {
     name: 'testcustomer',
     email: 'test@gmail.com',
     items: [
             {
               licenseName: 'Private',
               licensePrice: 2
             },
             {
               licenseName: 'Public',
               licensePrice: 4
             }
            ],
     totalPrice: 6
}
```

Then I pass this object to mvc controller using ajax

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/TestPayment/ChargeTest',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(cartStorage),
        success: function(response){
            if (response != null) {  
                alert(response);  
            } else {  
                alert("Something went wrong");  
            }  
        }    
    });
```

Here's the viewmodel associated with this method

```
namespace Web.ViewModels.Payment
{
    public class Items
    {
        public string licenseName { get; set; }
        public int licensePrice { get; set; }
    }

    public class PayerInfo
    {
        public int totalPrice { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public Items Items { get; set; }
    } 
}
```

Here's the mvc controller method, which processes the ajax request

```
   [HttpPost]
        public ContentResult ChargeTest([FromBody] PayerInfo model)
        {
            String FullName = model.name;
        }
```

But when the server executes the controller method, the model turns out to be null. 
However, if I comment out the Items class and the instance creation in the PayerInfo class in the viewmodel, then the model is being forwarded successfully and all the data is stored, I'm just having the problem with the list inside of js object. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The item in your model is single object and you are trying to pass in your json object a list of item! Try to change the item property to ‘List<Item> Items’

Comment: yes i think thats the problem. you should also take a look at custom modelbinder. inherit from DefaultModelBinder, and set with ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new MyModelBinder. then you can debug every property that gets bound.

Comment: @MoeJallaq that actually works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`items` in your json object is a list. So you need to change the type of `Items` in your c# model to a list.

```
namespace Web.ViewModels.Payment
{
    public class Items
    {
        public string licenseName { get; set; }
        public int licensePrice { get; set; }
    }

    public class PayerInfo
    {
        public int totalPrice { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public List<Items> Items { get; set; }
    } 
}
```